# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get this ([minimal working example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/moviewriter.html)) code to compile in a virtual environment on Anaconda which I've set up in a supercomputing cluster:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as manimation

FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
metadata = dict(title='Movie Test', artist='Matplotlib',
            comment='Movie support!')
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, metadata=metadata)

fig = plt.figure()
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'k-o')

plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)

x0, y0 = 0, 0

with writer.saving(fig, "writer_test.mp4", 100):
    for i in range(100):
        x0 += 0.1 * np.random.randn()
        y0 += 0.1 * np.random.randn()
        l.set_data(x0, y0)
        writer.grab_frame()
```

The thing is, this code **works absolutely fine on my local machine** (MacOSX) - Anaconda distribution; Python 2.7; same matplotlib and numpy version, and I have ffmpeg on Anaconda; I have ffmpeg on the cluster as well, albeit at a different version to the one on Python (but no issue with this on my local machine). When I run the code on the **cluster**, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "movie_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    writer.grab_frame()
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 241, in saving
    self.finish()
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 367, in finish
    self.cleanup()
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 405, in cleanup
    out, err = self._proc.communicate()
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 927, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1713, in _communicate
    orig_timeout)
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1769, in _communicate_with_poll
    register_and_append(self.stdout, select_POLLIN_POLLPRI)
  File "~/anaconda2/envs/test_movie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1748, in register_and_append
    poller.register(file_obj.fileno(), eventmask)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

All the searches I've made correspond to relatively simple text write in/out operations, but not for videos. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error is pretty minor - I had to import the cluster's matplotlib. I have no idea why this is the case, since matplotlib is already incorporated into the Python package.